# Collectd Python register_read error

Tags: python, plugins, grafana, collectd

I'm trying to follow [these](https://grafana.net/dashboards/235) instructions for a MySQL dashboard, however when I try to run **[mysql.py](https://github.com/chrisboulton/collectd-python-mysql/)** script, it gives me the following error:

```
  File "mysql.py", line 565, in <module>
    collectd.register_read(read_callback)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register_read'
```

I couldn't find any information on the internet about this error, so I am asking your help :)

Comment: I too had the same issue, and trying to debug collectd python plugin, but unable to get proper documentation about this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python -m collectd mysql.py
```

And if you have a problem using this plugin with `collectd` then put `mysql.py` file in python include path. To check it, use

```
python -v
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python', some_other_paths]
```

To make sure that the plugin works check `collectd` logs. You can do that in multiple ways:

1. Check the output of `sudo service collectd status` or
2. Check `collectd` log file

In both situations you should see something like this

```
[date] mysql plugin: Sending value: ...
```

Note 1: output of `sudo service collectd status` is limited and can show something else. If that's the case use log file
Note 2: to get the output enable plugin `logfile` and configure the path to the log file, eg.

```
<Plugin logfile>
    LogLevel "info"
    File "/var/log/collectd.log"
    Timestamp true
    PrintSeverity false
</Plugin>
```

> LogLevel `info` is the highest log level for most installations. Only `debug` is higher but it's available only if `collectd` was compiled with debugging support.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you cannot run collectd plugins outside of collectd i.e. as a standalone script because Collectd runs them through the embedded Python interpreter as described [here](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-python.5.shtml%20here)
You have to do the following:

1. Create your plugin config:

```
$ vi /etc/collectd.d/myplugin.conf # your path may vary
```

LoadPlugin Python
<Plugin python>
 ModulePath "/etc/collectd/python"
 LogTraces true
 Interactive false
 <Module myplugin>
   arg1 value1
 </Module> 
</Plugin>

The above section says -

- I have a plugin called myplugin.py present in /etc/collectd/python dir.

  - It is a non interactive plugin
  - I feed it input as - arg1=value1

Dump your plugin in /etc/collectd/python # same name as Module but with .py

Restart collectd and watch your logs by enabling the logfile plugin as mentioned above.

Check out a few samples plugins out there to see what goes inside a plugin - [iostat](https://github.com/deniszh/collectd-iostat-python), [redis](https://github.com/powdahound/redis-collectd-plugin)